# OpenFileDialog Control - How Can I Grab the Selected Path and Show it in a Text Box?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Here is my snippet:

```
private void btnBrowseCInv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ofdBrowseVInv.Title = "Locate Customer Invoice File";
  ofdBrowseVInv.Filter = "Portable Document Format (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
  ofdBrowseVInv.FileName = "";
  ofdBrowseVInv.FilterIndex = 0;

  ofdBrowseVInv.InitialDirectory = "";

  ofdBrowseVInv.CheckFileExists = true;
  ofdBrowseVInv.CheckPathExists = true;

  if (ofdBrowseVInv.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
  {
     //txtInvoicePathCInv.Text = ofdBrowseVInv... What property should i use?
  }
}
```

As you see below, once a user pick a file and click open. I want the selected path to show on the pointed text box which is named "txtInvoicePathCInv". Any idea?

I'm using Windows Application...

[alt text http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/54/99763211.jpg](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/54/99763211.jpg)

Comment: +1 style points for adding a screenshot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) property:

```
txtInvoicePathCInv.Text = ofdBrowseVInv.FileName;
```

This will give you the whole path, but you can always just use the directory part of it, using [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx):

```
txtInvoicePathCInv.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofdBrowseVInv.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofdBrowseVInv.FileName); 
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ofdBrowseVInv.FileName);
```